# Synchronization logic for persisting list of items to a DB - In code or SQL?

Tags: c#, java, sql

I have a list of items displayed in the UI.
They are in the form: 
**Name** (dropdown), **attribute1** (textbox), **attribute2** (textbox)
The **Name** functions as a unique key identifying a unique item (primary key).

These values are displayed in a list and user has option to create, update attribute
and delete values from the list

Now say user deletes some items belonging to certain row in the UI and then adds new items belonging to the same name

Then the user presses save for the entire list of items

Now to implement the persistence logic for this case I have multiple options:

1. I perform all my business logic at a SQL level
   I have to make sure that duplicate names are not entered in the DB so I handle this at a DB level by writing my SQL queries in such a manner that the query checks first if a entry of the similar name exists, if it exists it updates else inserts.
2. I perform my business logic at the code level i.e. I reload all the data again at the time of saving and compare and synchronize matching items and then decide that I have to insert certain items and delete others.
3. I maintain a IsDirty flag on each of the items and the moment anything is changed client side I update the IsDirty, anything marked with isDirty would have to be updated, any new items added would still have to be checked at a SQL level for duplicate name. But the difference in this method is that we do not have to reload the data from the database.
4. I delete all items from the database and reinsert all the items as present in the UI (I guess this is the worst way).

Which option should I go for, what is the best practice for persisting a list of items for web apps?

Where should the synchronization logic go?

Is it wise to put some syncing logic at the db level and checking that if name exists do not insert but just update?

Should this logic exist at a SQL level or at the code level (like Java or C# level)?

Is there any name (design pattern) for this?

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for the active record design pattern / object persistence

Comment: Active Record typically concerns itself with saving a single record/row in the database, but in case we have a list of objects and we are doing a batch save of the list then how do we sync the new data with the already existing data in the DB while simultaneously taking care of unique key constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@SeaHorse: As you mentioned the item 4 is the worst in the world.. so please disregard this option without doubts.

If I would need to take a decision I would choose the 1) approach and create the CRUD stored procedures on the database side, and create the logic on the domain to just call the stored procedures. With this approach, you avoid to open the domain code if you need to refactor something and instead, you quickly perform code updates on the stored procedures which are more modular and manageable components.